# Showing Existence, Uniqueness, and Maximal Solution to System of Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The initial value problem is:

> $\left\{\begin{matrix}
> x_{1}'=5x_{1}-2x_{2}\\ 
> x_{2}'=4x_{1}-x_{2}
> \end{matrix}\right.,\left\{\begin{matrix}
> x_{1}(\tau)=1\\ 
> x_{2}(\tau)=0
> \end{matrix}\right.$

What I did was define $f_{1}(t,x_{1},x_{2})=5x_{1}-2x_{2}$ and $f_{2}(t,x_{1},x_{2})=4x_{1}-x_{2}$. Both domains for each function is $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Since they are both polynomials, they are both continuous on their domains. Also $(\tau,1),(\tau,0)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$, and so by Peano's existence theorem, there exists at least one solution.

For uniqueness, I wanted to use partial derivatives. I am not sure if I was supposed to calculate each partial derivative for each function?

$\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_{1}}=5,\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_{2}}=-2,\frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial x_{1}}=4,\frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial x_{2}}=-1$

They are all continuous, and so the solution that exists is unique.

For the maximal solution part, do I solve the system? And how do I do that?

Comment: The system is uniformly Lipschitz on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$. The usual Picard theorem.

Comment: Also, it's a linear system, so you can write down the solution explicitly.

Comment: Is my method using partial derivatives correct though?

Comment: You computed the derivatives and then made a leap to uniqueness without explaining why. Perhaps elaborating the connection might help you progress to the maximal part. (A solution exists for all $\mathbb{R}$.)